# lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not

Tags: json, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Amazon SDK to upload document to CloudSearch. The document is formatted into JSON. When I try to upload the data it gives me below error-

```
{ ["lexical error: inside a string, '\' occurs before a character which it may not.
          attern can be escaped with a \ some\ file will match a file 
                     (right here) ------^
 (near operation with index 1; document_id 14266553008620)"] }
```

I have used [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON file and it was successfullt validating.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I'd guess replacing the single backslash with a double backslash (ie a literal backslash) might work.

Comment: Ryan..you nailed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by replacing the single backslash with a double backslash (ie a literal backslash).